# ASP net mvc site.css keeps showing even when not referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dnx

I created an Asp.net 5 web application via "yo aspnet". I downloaded a new bootstrap.min.css and added it in css folder. I then changed _Layout.cshtml and gulpfile.js to reference bootstrap.min.css instead of the default site.min.css (screenshot below).

[image]

[image]

The problem is when I run the site via dnx web the site still uses site.min.css even though no part of my code references site.min.css anymore. I'm not sure what is happening now?

[image]

If I manually change the site.min.css via devtools I can see the correct theme appply.
[image]

Comment: Check if you have reference on `App_Start -> BundleConfig.cs` file.

Comment: @SeM I think BundleConfig.cs is not used in asp.net 5. I just searched it now and saw that the gulp and _Layout.cshtml is what asp.net 5 uses. I tried searching all my files and I do not have a site.min.css reference anymore. I know as a workaround I could just put bootstrap.min.css content to site.min.css but then again I want to know what went wrong with what I am doing.

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try to find "site.css" string on your whole solution.

Comment: @SeM That did the trick! silly me :s Thanks. You can put that as answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear your browser cache and try to find `site.css` string on your whole solution.